# appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.someController memory leak?

Tags: ios5, memory-leaks, ipad-2, low-memory

It is showing as low memory on this line/code

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = preVC;
```

My code: -

```
PreViewController *preVC = [[PreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PreViewController" bundle:nil];
preVC.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
[self.view removeFromSuperview]; // Memory leak .6%
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = preVC; // Memory leak 46.4%
[preVC release];
```

please help, correct or suggest me to release the memory or alternative solution for the problem, where I have done wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` this is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @trapper Any alternative for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN app delegate i didFinishLaunching  u have to set your RootViewController at run time on thrugh  mainWindow.Xib